# Using a ViewComponent not known at compile time

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm starting a new ASP.Net MVC Core project and I'm trying to figure out how I could do the following:

I have part of the application for which I want to be able to add "plugins" which are not known at compile time. I have a page, in which I want to add a "component" which can come from external sources.

For example, I have a page with basic information. Let's say I'm building a house sales software. I have basic information about houses that are the same for all, but I have a drop-down list that, depending on existing plugins and other information, displays a component on the page that isn't necessarly known at compile time.

I've looked at ViewComponents, but it seems that they are a bit similar as Partial Views, and using InvokeAsync seems that it means that you have to know it at compile time.

Further, how would you store data for those ViewComponents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View components do not need to be known at compile time. They can be referenced at runtime but there are a few tricks. First, the `cshtml` files in the class library need to be included as embedded resources. This can be done by adding the following to the project.json for the class library:

```
"buildOptions": {
   "embed": "Views/**/*.cshtml"
}
```

In the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method of your web app, you need to add an embedded file provider to the `RazorViewEngineOptions`. Here is an example doing that for a known assembly.

```
    //Get a reference to the assembly that contains the view components
var assembly = typeof(ViewComponentLibrary.ViewComponents.SimpleViewComponent).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

//Create an EmbeddedFileProvider for that assembly
var embeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
    assembly,
    "ViewComponentLibrary"
);

//Add the file provider to the Razor view engine
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{                
    options.FileProviders.Add(embeddedFileProvider);
});
```

In your case you will need to load those assemblies dynamically which can be done using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath` for each assembly found in your plugin directory.

```
var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
```

It is difficult to answer the question of how you would store data for the view component without knowing more about your application and specific use case.

I have outlined the process of using view components from a class library in a blog post here: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/07/16/loading-view-components-from-a-class-library-in-asp-net-core.aspx